# Kerning on the boundary between mathmode and textmode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, kerning

Consider the following code: `If $x ∈ X$, then $y ∈ Y$.`. When it is rendered by TeX, the space between “X” and “,” and similary between “Y” and “.” seems to be too big. Is there any problem with kerning on the boundary between the mathmode and textmode? And if so, is there any (possibly standard and general) solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no automatic kerning, in fact TeX inserts a space with value `\mathsurround` before and after each math expression, although this usually has its default value of 0pt.

You can of course add explicit negative space at the end of the math or just after it.

Alternatively if you make the characters adjacent TeX has a chance to adjust the space:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

If $x\in X$, then $y\in Y$.


If $x\in X,$ then $y\in Y.$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wonder why there is no automatic kerning, since TeX was created to produce high quality typesetting of mathematical texts and this seems to be a typical example of a mathematical typesetting, or isn't it?

Comment: @user87690 TeX automatic kerns are always specified at the font level for adjacent characters in the same font. You don't get automatic kerning with `\textbf{A}V` or `A\hbox{}V` either. This case is similar, typically the math font and text font are different, and even if they are the same in this case, there is a math-off node and a kern of \mathsurround in between.

Comment: I understand. I just wonder if it bothers anybody else and if there is any robust solution.

Comment: @user87690 updated answer with examples

Comment: @user87690 like the manual addition of `\/` italic correction it is always possible (if tiresome) to add explicit spaces to get the best possible typography.

Comment: Well if mathmode and textmode use different fonts, wouldn't the punctation be potentially rendered differently? On the other hand, if it looks the same, why there isn't a font for both mathmode and textmode so the kerning-pair information can be applied?

Comment: @user87690 -- remember that when tex was first written, no font could contain more than 256 glyphs.  many flavors of tex still hold to that limit.  fonts just aren't big enough to hold all the glyphs that might need to be kerned.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Isn't the situation better with XeTeX or LuaTeX?

Comment: @user87690 -- in my current working environment, neither xetex or luatex are viable options, so i don't have any reliable information on that situation.  however, i know that if tfm files are used (the original tex situation), the capacity is too limited to make this information available, and if opentype fonts are used, i don't think there's a clear place to put this information in the tables.  in any event, it would be an enormous task to add the information, and i'm skeptical as to whether it can be handled just by kerning.